# Number of times we need to play a game until win an amount

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, probability-distributions

We have a box with 5 black and 5 white balls. 
We choose 2 balls and if they have the same color we win 2 dollars else we lose 1dollar.(After we finish a game we put the balls back in the box)

How many times we need to play to win more that  10 dollars with possibility 90%?

I believe that we have an exponential distribution after we have succes and fails and the possibility of win a game is 4/9 so to lose is 5/9 , but i can't understand how i can calculate the number of times  after i can lose money a lot of times after i win game or before a game.

P(win 2 dollars) = 4/9
P(lose 1 dollar) = 5/9
EX = -1 * 5/9 +2 * 4/9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your probability of winning?

$P(win) = \frac {4}{9}$

What is your probability of losing?

$P(loss) = \frac {5}{9}$

What is your expectation on a single play?

$E = 2P(win) - P(loss) = \frac {3}{9} = \frac {1}{3}$

Does this game have positive expectation? 
Yes.

If the game has negative expectation, is it reasonable to have high confidence that you will be ahead after some large number of plays? 
No.

This will follow a Bernoulli distribution.  And if you play enough games will be approximately a normal distribution.

What is your variance?  $(2-\frac 13)^2\frac {4}{9} + (-1-\frac 13)^2\frac {5}{9} = \frac{20}{9}$

What is your Standard Deviation? $\sqrt {\frac {20}{9}} = \frac {2\sqrt 5}{3}$

What is your expected winnings after $n$ plays? $\frac {n}{3}$

What is your Standard Deviation after $n$ plays? $\frac {2\sqrt {5}}{3}\sqrt n$

90% confidence is about 1.3 standard deviations.

$\frac {\frac{n}{3} - 10}{\frac {2\sqrt 5}{3}\sqrt n} = 1.3\\
\frac {n - 30}{2\sqrt {5n}} \approx 1.3\\
n -2.6\sqrt{5n} - 30 = 0\\
\sqrt n  \approx 1.3\sqrt 5 + \sqrt {1.69\cdot 5 + 30}\\
\sqrt n \approx 8.2\\
n \approx 67$

Comment: I have calculated standard deviation and mean . I belive that it is exponential distribution because we have repeats of a bernoulli experiment.The expected standard deviation is 1/3. Ex = -1 * 5/9 + 2 * 4/9.

Comment: Put your work into your original post of the question.

Comment: Could you explain me why after n plays the standard deviation and the expected winnings given from n/3 and var(x) * sqrt(n) ?